# Adding a second SSL for a second domain on a server - second domain is still using the first SSL Cert

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to add an ssl cert to a second domain on my server (AWS Amazon Linux)

I thought I enabled SNI correctly?  although probably not...

domain1 already has a functioning SSL cert.
First attempt I was getting stuck in a redirect loop.
Second (current) attempt it now gives me a 403/Forbidden on the /users/login/ directory.

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
```

base httpd.conf:
    ...
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443
...
```

domain1.conf:

```
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerAdmin hostmaster@domain1.com
   ServerName domain1.com

   SSLEngine On
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

   SSLCertificateFile /var/www/domain1.com/apache_includes/secure/domain1.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/domain1.com/apache_includes/secure/domain1.com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/domain1.com/apache_includes/secure/gd_bundle.crt

   ProxyPreserveHost On

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol https
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/

   SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

domain2.conf:

```
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>

   ServerAdmin hostmaster@domain1.com

   ServerName domain2.com
   ServerAlias www.domain2.com #prob don't need this....

   SSLEngine On
   SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

   SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

   SSLCertificateFile /var/www/domain2.com/apache_includes/secure/domain2.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/domain2.com/apache_includes/secure/domain2.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/domain2.com/apache_includes/secure/bundle.crt

   ProxyPreserveHost On

   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Protocol https
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1/

   SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apache 2.2 The `NameVirtualHost` directive must match the `<VirtualHost>` blocks (so use `<VirtualHost *:443>` for both blocks)

The `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives inside the `<VirtualHost>` block are used to select which block to serve based on the incoming request.

Comment: I did change the line  <VirtualHost domain2.com:443> to <VirtualHost *:443>, but had no change in result.